# wordpress loop clarifications about contents

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

To learn more about the latest version of WordPress, I'm reading the documentation. I've some questions about the [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). As I can understand this is the basic function that will display contents inside WordPress pages. I want to understand if this function is responsible to display only the posts or also it will display pages. If this will display both, how I can customize the appearance of the post list to differentiate it from the site pages contents?
I want to make some pages for my website and one of these will only be responsible to display a list of posts, so it will be a blog and not really a page. I'm a bit confused about, every question or article I've read talk about the loop as necessary to display contents.

This means that with this basic code I will display all my page contents?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Defaultly, the loop will have the content of the page or post or posts list, depending on the URL and template hierarchy. So if you create a custom page, content will be the content of the page. But you can create a WP_Query to display posts on a page, and create another loop from the query results.

Comment: @Mtxz ok, so basically I can design every page to display only what I want, this by creating an appropriate instance of WP_Query?

Comment: Yes. And on the page, default the content will be the content of the page wysiwyg. You can use it or not, and then make your Query to display some posts.